# AVAudioPlayer is nil after i alloc init

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, xcode6, avaudioplayer

i'm stuck at AVAudioPlayer in my project.the scenario is,
in CollectionViewController's "didSelectItemAtIndexPath" method, i alloc and init AVAudioPlayer like bellow,

```
dict=[plist objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    NSURL* urlPath=[NSURL new];
    urlPath=[NSURL URLWithString:[dict objectForKey:@"FilePath"]];
     NSError *error = nil;
    self.player=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:urlPath error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Error[%@]",[error localizedDescription]);
    [self.player setDelegate:self];
    [self.player prepareToPlay];
```

but after this,it still remains nill..
first, i tried without making property of player.but no luck....
so i try with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856332/avaudioplayer-no-sound)

Comment: had you double check the urlPath is not nil?

Comment: @WorldOfWarcraft "urlPath" is not nil..

Comment: You put your code in`didSelectItemAtIndexPath`, that means the player init only when you selected.

Comment: post your code here .

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {


    NSLog(@" selected data ==%@",[yoururlarray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]);

 urlPath=[yoururlarray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]);

    self.player=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:urlPath error:nil];
    [self.player setDelegate:self];
    [self.player prepareToPlay];


    }
```